# A-frame fadeOut primitives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, aframe

I've got a trouble with a-frame.
Is here way to remove a component or primitive from scene with delay? Like fadeOut in jQuery?

should I check every tick for `opacity` CSS property or special className or smth like that?

If I want to fadeOut a primitive from `ng-repeat`, should I use ng-animate and check for `.ng-leave` class?

Ideally, I want to declare algorythm in `remove()` function of my component or primitive. For example, if I return a Promise in remove() function, then remove `Object3D` on promise resolve. But that's implemented not in this way, and I've got stuck :(

look example: http://codepen.io/Disorrder/pen/BWBKpb

Comment: Are you able to create a demo in Codepen such as this default scene: http://codepen.io/mozvr/pen/BjygdO ?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle yep, look at this codePen: http://codepen.io/Disorrder/pen/BWBKpb

Answer (score 1):

I may be confused, are you trying to remove it or just fade it out from view? You may consider using the built-in `Animations` with A-Frame.  Examples here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/animations.html#begin

This wouldn't remove it, but jQuery (per your second question) does not remove the element on [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: Well, I can't manage this ng-repeat process directly. I wish cubes will disappear with animations when DOM object was deleted from scene. You're right, fadeOut don't remove DOM, but I just wanna make same effect. It seems, I should watch css property every tick or something like that to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/jdoyle/pen/aJoVJj

As far as I can tell, the opacity CSS property will have no effect on objects in the scene. Because of this, I don't think you will be able to use `.ng-leave`. The only way to animate the opacity is through the animation component, or programmatically.

Using the `$timeout` provider, and knowing the animation duration, you could set something up like this:

```
<a-box ng-repeat="box in page.getActiveBoxes() track by box.id"
         ng-class="{animated: page.animate}"
         position="{{box.position}}"
         rotation="0 45 0"
         width="0.6" height="1" depth="0.6"
         color="{{box.color}}"
    >
  <a-animation attribute="opacity" begin="fadeOut" duration="5000" to="0"></a-animation>
</a-box>

fadeOut() {
  var id = this.getRandomInt(0, this.boxes.length-1);
  document.querySelector('#box-' + id).emit('fadeOut');
  this.$timeout(function() {
    // you can now delete the primitive
  }, 5000 + 50);  // added 50ms for good measure
}

getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but I can't really think of another way.

Another disappointment, angular interpolation does not work for duration property of animation. Duration once set, cannot be changed. This will not work:

```
<a-animation attribute="opacity" duration="{{page.animationDuration}}" begin="fadeOut" to="0"></a-animation>
```

Comment: The latter might be a problem with <a-animation> because setting properties via JS has multiple issues. It might be deprecated in the future in favour of a compenent based solution according to Kevin.